# Why is that gold coin glowing green?

Tags: dungeon-boss

Can anyone tell me why the gold coin at the top of the screen has started glowing green?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this happen a few times now and it is just a graphical glitch as far as I can see from doing something like, collecting your gold from your dungeon and then exiting to the home menu before the animation finishes playing or the like. A simple in and out of the game, collecting gold from some where else, etc has always cleared this up for me.